# Label NAs in ggplot2 bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe for which I have create a column chart.

```
              Area IMD_Score
1  East Devon 005A        NA
2       East Devon        NA
3            Devon  65.00236
4               SW  60.28269
5          England  57.61097
6         IMD - Q3  56.90886
7 Eastern Locality  55.07258

xAxisTitle <- "IMD Score"
chartTitle <- "Overall IMD score 2015"

  latestChart = ggplot(dataset, aes_string(y=colnames(dataset[2]), x=colnames(dataset[1]) ) ) + 
    geom_col(fill="#1f78b4") + 
    coord_flip() +
    scale_x_discrete(dataset$Area) + 
    labs(y=xAxisTitle, title=chartTitle) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),panel.ontop = TRUE,
          panel.grid = element_line(colour = "grey", size=0.25, linetype = "dashed"),
          axis.title.y=element_blank()
        ) +
    geom_label(label=dataset$IMD_Score, na.rm=FALSE)
```

Adding data labels causes me two problems:
1 Using `geom_text(label=dataset$IMD_Score, na.rm=FALSE)` displays labels but I'd ideally like them to be inside the bars.  I've tried adding `position = position_stack(vjust = 1)` but that results in "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): label" which I'm guessing is something to do with "Warning messages 1: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (position_stack)."

2 For rows with NA I would like to add a label to show that that the value is NA rather than zero.

Ultimately I'd like to end up with something like the linked image.

Example chart

[image]

Any ideas appreciated.

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
dataset <-
structure(list(Area = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 
5L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("Devon", "East Devon", 
"East Devon 005A", "Eastern Locality", "England", 
"IMD - Q3", "SW"), class = "factor"), IMD_Score = 
c(NA, NA, 65.00236, 60.28269, 57.61097, 56.90886, 
55.07258)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: The posted code throws `Error in rlang::list2(..., title = title, subtitle = subtitle, caption = caption,  :  object 'xAxisTitle' not found`. Please, also post the value of `chartTitle`.

Comment: please make your data in reproducible form.

Comment: @RuiBarradas - xAxisTitle = "IMD Score" and chartTitle = "Overall IMD score 2015"

Comment: @sindri_baldur Sorry, I'm new here - what do you mean by make my data in reporducible form?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean use `dput()` and paste the output here.

Comment: @sindri_baldur The output of dput(latestChart) is too long for a comment - should I edit the original post to include it?

Comment: perhaps `dput(head(latestChart, 10))`?

Comment: @sindri_baldur No, it's the output of `dput(dataset)` that should be posted. I have done so, see the question edit.

Comment: Instead of `geom_label` try `geom_text(aes(label = IMD_Score, hjust = 2), colour = "white", na.rm = FALSE)`. It will get you close to what you want.

Comment: @MarkPainter: you might be interested in this too https://github.com/njtierney/naniar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#reproduce your dataset
dataset <- data.frame(
  Area = c(
    "East Devon 005A",
    "East Devon",
    "Devon",
    "SW",
    "England",
    "IMD - Q3",
    "Eastern Locality"
  ),
  IMD_Score = c(NA,
                NA,
                65.00236,
                60.28269,
                57.61097,
                56.90886,
                55.07258)
)
# this a trick to keep rows with NA
dataset$IMD_Score_to_plot <- if_else(is.na(dataset$IMD_Score),
                                     0,
                                     dataset$IMD_Score)
#create the label with No data available
dataset$IMD_Score_label <- if_else(dataset$IMD_Score_to_plot == 0,
                                   "No data available",
                                   "")
#plot (the clue is using two geom_text)
latestChart = ggplot(dataset, aes_string(y = colnames(dataset[3]), x = colnames(dataset[1]))) +
  geom_col(fill = "#1f78b4") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(dataset$Area) +
  labs(y = "xAxisTitle", title = "chartTitle") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    panel.ontop = TRUE,
    panel.grid = element_line(
      colour = "grey",
      size = 0.25,
      linetype = "dashed"
    ),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  geom_text(
    label = dataset$IMD_Score_to_plot,
    na.rm = FALSE,
    vjust = 0.5,
    hjust = 5
  ) +
  geom_text(label = dataset$IMD_Score_label,
            vjust = 0.5,
            hjust = 0)
latestChart
```

this is the output and I think it's what you want:[image]

Comment: Ideal, thanks.  Just needed to change `dataset$IMD_Score_label` to look at the original `IMD_Score` rather than the newly created column as I don't want "No data available" where the correct data is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Modified your code a bit. Mainly adding two `geom_text` and removing the `geom_label`:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(y = IMD_Score, x = Area)) + 
  geom_col(fill="#1f78b4") + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete() + 
  labs(y=xAxisTitle, title=chartTitle) +
  geom_text(aes(label= round(IMD_Score, 2), y = IMD_Score - 3), col = "white", size = 4) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(is.na(IMD_Score), "No data available", ""), y = 3), col = "gray", hjust = 0) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),panel.ontop = TRUE,
    panel.grid = element_line(colour = "grey", size=0.25, linetype = "dashed"),
    axis.title.y=element_blank()
  )
```

[image]